# how to refresh page after certain amount of time in click handler

Tags: javascript

In my below code / JS. I would simply like to 'refresh' the page after the click handler fires *(or after button is clicked)*.. after about 2 or 3 seconds after the click has fired. So basically button clicked, 2-3 seconds have passed and then the page refreshes. I want to do it with pure JS, not jQuery or use of `<meta>`

Below is my JS:

```
   $('.download-pdf').click(function() {

   // I would like to add here

    notChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent();
    notChecked.hide();
    yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent();

    $.each(yesChecked, function( index, el ) {
      $(el).show().html(texts[$(el).attr('id')]);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setTimeout()`

```
 setTimeout(function(){
      location.reload();
     },3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

To reload your page after 2 sec, use following
`setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload()}, 2000);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple `settimeout()` function to delay a function after a certain amount of time

You can use `location.reload();` to refresh a page, I use it myself after updating data.

The delayinmiliseconds represents the amount of seconds you want before the page reloads. It is represented in milliseconds, so 1 seconds/1000. In this case you would want to put 3000.

Here is an example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     location.reload();
}, thedelayinmiliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.download-pdf').click(function(event) {

    //remove default click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    //refresh page after 3 seconds
    setTimout( 'window.location.reload()', 3000);


    notChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent();
    notChecked.hide();
    yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent();

    $.each(yesChecked, function( index, el ) {
      $(el).show().html(texts[$(el).attr('id')]);
    });

}
```